# Angular.js filter by element of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, filter

I have an array of json obects like:

```
 $scope.users = [
    {name:'Maria',age:25,skills["Angular.js","Node.js"]},
    {name:'Maxime',age:28,skills["HTML","MongoDB"]},
    {name:'Noemie',age:28,skills["CSS","MongoDB"]}
 ]
```

i want to make a search engine. if the user can enter one or multiples words and then my app will filter my variable.

For example, the user enter "28" and "MongoDB", then I put the two queries in an array like

```
$scope.queries = [28,"MongoDB"]
```

and filter my array : $scope.users with it.

Please note that $scope.users is not as simple as the exemple and it have somes other array wich contain array etc... So i'll prefer a function to "simply" search for keywords

I would like to know how to do a function or filter.

Comment: I would put this search function in the backend and let SQL handle it.  If your dataset get huge, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: yes, afeter thinking about it, i would do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very optimal, but you can try this

```
var filterQueries = [28,"MongoDB"];
var filteredResults = $scope.users.filter(function(obj){
  var match = false;
  filterQueries.forEach(function(query){
    if ( obj.name == query || obj.age == query || obj.skills.indexOf( query ) != -1 ) 
    {
       match = true; //assuming you want any of the query to be found rather than all
    }
  });
  return match;
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
  
var users = [
    {name:'Maria',age:25,skills : ["Angular.js","Node.js"]},
    {name:'Maxime',age:28,skills : ["HTML","MongoDB"]},
    {name:'Noemie',age:28,skills : ["CSS","MongoDB"]}
];

var filterQueries = [28,"MongoDB"];
var filteredResults = users.filter(function(obj){
  var match = false;
  filterQueries.forEach(function(query){
    if ( obj.name == query || obj.age == query || obj.skills.indexOf( query ) != -1 ) 
    {
       match = true; //assuming you want any of the query to be found rather than all
    }
  });
  return match;
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify( filteredResults, 0, 4 )
```